# Convergence to $\operatorname{sgn}(x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

Define $f_n, f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ as 
$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
-1, &x \in \left(-\infty, -\frac{1}{n}\right)\\
nx, &x \in \left[-\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}\right]\\
1, &x \in \left(\frac{1}{n}, \infty\right)
\end{cases}$$
and
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
-1, &x \in \left(-\infty, 0\right)\\
1, &x \in \left[0, \infty\right)
\end{cases}
$$
Does $f_n$ converge to $f$? If not, how do I modify $f_n$ so that it converges to $f$?

Comment: What is $f_n(0)$ for each $n$? Now you know if $f_n \to f$ or not. Note that at every other point $x$, $f_n(x) \to f(x)$. So how would you modify $f$?

Comment: I see, $f_n(0)$ converges to $0$. The question is, how do I modify $f_n$ so that I get a convergence to $f$?